# Stop tkinter GUI with a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a GUI with tkinter and I need help.
I have two buttons, one for starting my code and another one for exit the GUI and stop the code running. Here is part of my code:

```
def close_app():
    window.destroy()
    

def run_app():
    .... do something...

window = tk.Tk() #start of the app

button_run = tk.Button(frame_bottom, text = "Search", command = run_app)
button_run.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='w', padx=100, pady=2)
button_close = tk.Button(frame_bottom, text = "Exit", command = close_app)
button_close.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='e', padx=100, pady=2)

window.mainloop() #end of the app
```

The problem is that when I press "Exit" button the GUI does not respond anymore and the code still continues in the background. How can I stop the execution of the program with my Exit button?
I tried also to delete the Exit button and to stop the code simply closing the GUI, but the problem is the same, after a while "not respondind" appears. How can I solve it?

Comment: Based on posted code, pressing `Exit` button should not make the program not responding.  It should be something else, so better provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted it's hard to tell, but if `run_app` is doing something that takes very long the function won't be stopped - that's why your GUI is freezing.

If `run_app` contains a loop, setting a global variable in `close_app` then checking inside the loop if that variable is set and if it is stopping the loop would be the solution:

```py
import time
import tkinter as tk

exit_app = False

def close_app():
    exit_app = True
    window.destroy()

def run_app():
    for i in range(100):
        if exit_app:
            break
        time.sleep(1)

window = tk.Tk()

button_run = tk.Button(frame_bottom, text = "Search", command = run_app)
button_run.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='w', padx=100, pady=2)
button_close = tk.Button(frame_bottom, text = "Exit", command = close_app)
button_close.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='e', padx=100, pady=2)

window.mainloop()
```

(Not tested as your code does not define `frame_bottom`)

If it doesn't run in a loop, the last solution would be to call `sys.exit` in `close_app` which *should* exit yur script immediately.